# Huge unwanted delays between consecutive requests in scrapy

Tags: python, concurrency, web-scraping, scrapy

I felt scrapy is not giving me good performance in terms of links per second. To debug , I configured scrapy to sent requests via squid proxy in and recorded all the requests that passed through the proxy.

From my analysis it was clear scrapy is not even utilising 20% of throughput.
We had given 8 concurrent requests per domain and following is the request utilisation graph we build

[image]

Each of the brown box above is a different HTTP requests.
We have 8 rows as we have 8 concurrent requests per domain.

As you can see there is a huge delay between 2 sets of consecutive concurrent requests.

I gave DOWNLOAD_DELAY as 0 , still its the same story.

Kindly advice what I can throttle so that scrapy utilizes all its throughput into downloading

I have also taken down any kind of processing involved after the HTML is received. Also I am using a memory queue.

Comment: Do you have some code and settings to share so the problem can be reproduced by others?